# Assigning value to an array of other class by creating an object

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class product
{
int productId[];
String productName,productType[];
float productPrice[];

public static void main(String...args)
{
    shop ob=new shop();
    ob.startshop();
}
}

class shop
{   
product obj;

void startshop()
{
    obj=new product();
    obj.productId()={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};
    obj.productName={"Cadbury","Parker Vector","Nescafe","kissan                   jam","Herbal oil","Garnier man's","Lays chips","Bourn bourn biscuits","Bournvita","Pepse"};
        obj.productType={"Chocolate","Stationary","Coffee","Jam","Oil","Face wash","chips","Biscuits","Health Supplement","Cold Drink"}
        obj.productPrice={20,150,80,65,30,79,10,20,140,24};
        Scanner oj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(obj.productName);
        boolean c=true;
        while(c==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Please press\n1 for view all products\n2 for         view product detail\n3 to exit shop");
            int ch=oj.nextInt();
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:viewAllProducts();
                    break;
                case 2:System.out.println("Enter product id to search      starting from 1001 to 1010");
                    int i=oj.nextInt();
                    viewProductDetail(i);
                    break;
                    case 3:System.out.println("You are out of shop :)");
                    c=false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    void viewAllProducts()
    {   System.out.println("ID\t\tNAME\t\tTYPE\t\tPRICE");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj.prductId[i]+"\t\t"+obj.productName[i]+"\t\t+"+obj.product    Type[i]+"\t\t"+obj.productPrice[i]);
        }
    }
    void viewProductDetail(int id)
    {
        int k=15;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
        if(obj.productId[i]==id)
        k=i;
        }
        if(k<10)
        {
            System.out.println("Product id "+obj.productId[k]);
            System.out.println("Product name "+obj.productName[k]);
            System.out.println("Product type "+obj.productType[k]);
            System.out.println("Product price "obj.productPrice[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code due to following lines the code is giving error

> obj.productId()={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};
>         obj.productName={"Cadbury","Parker Vector","Nescafe","kissan
>   jam","Herbal oil","Garnier man's","Lays chips","Bourn bourn
>   biscuits","Bournvita","Pepse"};
>         obj.productType={"Chocolate","Stationary","Coffee","Jam","Oil","Face
>   wash","chips","Biscuits","Health Supplement","Cold Drink"};
>         obj.productPrice={20,150,80,65,30,79,10,20,140,24};

Please tell me if i am using a wrong syntax to initialize the instance variable of other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.productId()={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};` This syntax is wrong, `productId` is not a function, use it without the brackets.

Example -

```
obj.productId= new int[]{1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};
```

Comment: product.java:20: error: illegal start of expression
                obj.productId={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010
};
                              ^
product.java:20: error: not a statement
                obj.productId={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010
};
                               ^
product.java:20: error: ';' expected
                obj.productId={1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010
};

Comment: Please try the latest code. there is a `new int[]` in it.

Answer (score 1):

yes you are using a wrong syntax here. `obj.productId()` would be a function but in your case it is a parameter of the class `Product` Just write `obj.productId`.

But you have to keep in mind, that you can not use `int array[] = {example}` syntax after you created the parameter. You have to use this when u initialize your parameter.

You can do

```
float productPrice[] = {"0.0","1,1","2.2"};
```

but not

```
float productPrice[];
productPrice = {"0.0","1,1","2.2"};
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Is there any other way i can give value to my array in class shop?

Comment: If you want to use an array you can write yourself a method in the class 'product' like 'addToProductPrice(float price)'.  Alternatively you can use an ArrayList instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your Question in the following way and I am getting the expected results. Please go through.

```
package product;

/**
*
* @author sunil
*/

import java.util.*;


public class product
{
int productId[];
String productName[],productType[];
int productPrice[];

public static void main(String args [])
{
shop ob = new shop();
ob.startshop();
}

}

class shop{   

product obj;

void startshop()
{
obj = new product();
obj.productId = new int[]  
{1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010};
obj.productName= new String[]{"Cadbury","Parker Vector","Nescafe","kissan  
jam","Herbal oil","Garnier man's","Lays chips","Bourn bourn 
biscuits","Bournvita","Pepsi"};
    obj.productType = new String[] 
{"Chocolate","Stationary","Coffee","Jam","Oil","Face 
wash","chips","Biscuits","Health Supplement","Cold Drink"};
    obj.productPrice = new int[]{20,150,80,65,30,79,10,20,140,24};
    Scanner oj=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj.productId));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj.productName));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj.productType));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(obj.productPrice));
    boolean c=true;
    while(c==true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please press\n1 for view all products\n2 for 
    view product detail\n3 to exit shop");
        int ch=oj.nextInt();
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 1:viewAllProducts();
                break;
            case 2:System.out.println("Enter product id to search starting 
    from 1001 to 1010");
                int i=oj.nextInt();
                viewProductDetail(i);
                break;
                case 3:System.out.println("You are out of shop :)");
                c=false;
                break;
          }
       }
    }
    void viewAllProducts()
    {   System.out.println("ID\t\tNAME\t\tTYPE\t\tPRICE");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(obj.productId[i]+"\t\t"+obj.productName[i] 
+"\t\t+"+obj.productType[i]+"\t\t"+obj.productPrice[i]);
    }
}
void viewProductDetail(int id)
{
    int k=15;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    if(obj.productId[i]==id)
    k=i;
    }
    if(k<10)
    {
        System.out.println("Product id "+obj.productId[k]);
        System.out.println("Product name "+obj.productName[k]);
        System.out.println("Product type "+obj.productType[k]);
        System.out.println("Product price "+obj.productPrice[k]);
      }
   }
}
```